# Injecting Angular Dependencies?

Tags: angularjs

I'm in the process of learning angular. I hit a problem tonight that caused me a few hours of frustration. Though i found out what my problem was i don't know it caused the problem it did. I'm here to ask the details. Here is my angular controller:

```
(function () {
    var customersController = function ($scope, $log, customersFactory, appSettings) {
        $scope.sortBy = 'name';
        $scope.reverse = false;

        $scope.appSettings = appSettings;


        function init() {
            //$scope.customers = customersFactory.getCustomers();
            customersFactory.getCustomers()
                 .success(function (customers) {
                     $scope.customers = customers;
                 })
                 .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                     $log.log('');
                 });
        };

        init();

        $scope.doSort = function (propName) {
            $scope.sortBy = propName;
            $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
        };
    };

    customersController.$inject = ['$scope', 'customersFactory', 'appSettings'];

    angular.module('customersApp').controller('customersController', customersController);
}());
```

I've been told the following line:
`customersController.$inject = ['$scope', 'customersFactory', 'appSettings'];`
Is to protect from minification. For example if $scope becomes minified. It wasn't required but you could have problems when you minify.

As you can tell from my controller i forgot `'$log'`. Here is the error i was getting:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at init (http://localhost:8080/app/controllers/customersController.js:12:30)
    at new customersController (http://localhost:8080/app/controllers/customersController.js:21:9)
    at invoke (http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular.js:3869:17)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular.js:3880:23)
    at http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular.js:7134:28
    at link (http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular-route.min.js:7:248)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular.js:6579:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular.js:5986:15)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular.js:5891:30)
    at boundTranscludeFn (http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular.js:6005:21) <ng-view class="ng-scope">
```

I wasn't minifying my javascript so i wasn't expecting any errors. It was failing at the following line:

```
 customersFactory.getCustomers()
```

By the error it was giving me i kept on thinking it was telling me `getCustomers()` wasn't defined in my factory.

So my questions are:

1. Why did i get this error on an unminified javascript file?
2. Did i the error happen where it did because of where `$log.log('');` located? I would have expected it to happen when `$log.log('');` actually got called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your '$inject' call was telling Angular the string names of the services to match up with your controller.  Strings aren't minified which is why this avoids minification errors (even if the first parameter `$scope` is renamed into `a`, angular will know to send what it calls `$scope` into that first parameter).  So this benefits minified code, but affects both versions.

So, when you left $log out you told Angular that these services ['$scope', 'customersFactory', 'appSettings'] should be injected (in the specified order) into these parameters ($scope, $log, customersFactory, appSettings).

What happened is:

`$scope` went into `$scope`   (yay!)

`customersFactory` went into `$log`  (not what you wanted)

`appSettings` went into `customersFactory`   (sadness- this line `customersFactory.getCustomers()` will now try to call `getCustomers()` on the `appSettings` service)

`undefined` went into `appSettings`  (more sadness)

Answer (score 0):

here is your problem your declaration

```
customersController = function ($scope, $log, customersFactory, appSettings)
```

your injection

```
customersController.$inject = ['$scope', 'customersFactory', 'appSettings'];
```

what it should be

```
customersController.$inject = ['$scope','$log','customersFactory', 'appSettings'];
```

dependencies are injected in the order they are declared so in your case you where expecting to have a $log service and you where receiving customersFactory service as injected.